# Как открыть файл excel используя javax.swing?

Tags: java, excel

Считываю файл excel используя библиотеку Apache POI. На консоль выводится содержимое файла. Можно ли вывести содержимое не на консоль, а в отдельное окно(например используя библиотеку javax.swing)?

Очень запутался пока пробовал что-то сделать.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Часть 1 - чтение excel

```
public class Readsheet{
    static XSSFRow row;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new   File("1_2016_September.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);  

    Iterator < Row > rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()){
        row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
        Iterator < Cell > cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext()){
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            switch (cell.getCellType()){
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " \t" );
                break;

            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " \t" );
                break;

                    }
            }

        System.out.println();


        CompletedWorks History = new CompletedWorks(); //?
        History.displayFieldHistory.setText(???);      //?





        }

    fis.close();

    }
}
```

Часть 2 - это окно

```
public class CompletedWorks {       
    JPanel panelComplitedWorks;
    JPanel pTop;
    JPanel pCenter;

    JLabel thisDay;
    JCheckBox paidCheck;
    public JTextArea displayFieldHistory;  //?

    public CompletedWorks (){

    panelComplitedWorks= new JPanel();
    BorderLayout panelCW = new BorderLayout(1,1);
    panelComplitedWorks.setLayout(panelCW); 


    displayFieldHistory = new JTextArea(10, 10);
    displayFieldHistory.setLineWrap(true);
    displayFieldHistory.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    pCenter = new JPanel();
    GridLayout glH =new GridLayout(1,1);
    pCenter.setLayout(glH);

    pCenter.add(displayFieldHistory);

    panelComplitedWorks.add("Center",pCenter); 


    thisDay = new JLabel("Date");                                              
    paidCheck = new JCheckBox("salary");

    pTop = new JPanel();                                                        
    GridLayout gl2 =new GridLayout(1,2); 
    pTop.setLayout(gl2);

    pTop.add(thisDay);
    pTop.add(paidCheck);

    panelComplitedWorks.add("North",pTop);



    JFrame frameHistory = new JFrame("A list of completed orders"); 
    frameHistory.setContentPane(panelComplitedWorks);   
    frameHistory.pack();                            
    frameHistory.setLocation(500, 205);
    frameHistory.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletedWorks CW = new CompletedWorks();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как метод `setText` принимает строку, разумно сгенерировать для него строку.

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
while (rowIterator.hasNext()){
    row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                text.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                text.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                break;
        }
    }
    text.append("\n");
}

CompletedWorks History = new CompletedWorks();
History.displayFieldHistory.setText(text.toString());
```

Правда, лучше воспользоваться JTable вместо JTextArea. И поле displayFieldHistory сделать закрытым, а данные в него писать сеттером или передавать в конструктор формы. Да и код чтения файла вполне можно перенести в метод main или какой-нибудь другой класса формы.

Comment: Ага, ясно.
Попробую всё это сделать. Многие вещи делаю пока интуитивно и, понимаю, далеко не лучшим способом, а то и вовсе с ошибками и косяками, как в этот раз. Буду разбираться.
 
Исчерпывающий ответ. 
Вы очень помогли, спасибо большое!